# Is there a "and=" operator for boolean?

Tags: python, boolean, operators

There is the "+=" operator for, namely, int.

```
a = 5
a += 1
b = a == 6 # b is True
```

Is there a "and=" operator for bool?

```
a = True
a and= 5 > 6 # a is False
a and= 5 > 4 # a is still False
```

I know, this 'and=' operator would correspond to:

```
a = True
a = a and 5 > 6 # a is False
a = a and 5 > 4 # a is still False
```

But, I do this operation very often and I don’t think it looks very neat.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean only `1` or `0` values, that would be bitwise `and`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes - you can use `&=`.

```
a = True
a &= False  # a is now False
a &= True   # a is still False
```

You can similarly use `|=` for "or=".

It should be noted (as in the comments below) that this is actually a bitwise operation; it will have the expected behavior **only** if `a` starts out as a Boolean, and the operations are only carried out with Booleans.

Comment: This is the closest you can get in the present language, but it's not exactly what was asked for: these operators do *bitwise* and and or.  The difference matters when the values on either side aren't strictly booleans.

Comment: `&=` is bitwise operation, but the question is asking for boolean operation, you should point out the difference.

Comment: To use it in place of `and=` just wrap any non-boolean operands in `bool()`, which is effectively what regular `and` does.

Answer (score 4):

nrpeterson showed you how to use `&=` with boolean.

I show only what can happend if you mix boolean and integer

```
a = True
a &= 0 # a is 0
if a == False : print "hello" # "hello"

a = True
a &= 1 # a is 1
if a == False : print "hello" # nothing

a = True
a &= 2 # a is 0 (again)
if a == False : print "hello" # "hello"

a = True
a &= 3 # a is 1
if a == False : print "hello" # nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at the operator library:
http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

This allows you to do

```
a = True
a = operator.iand(a, 5>6) # a is False
```

Comment: It's nice to know this exists in `operator` module but it's not useful in most cases

Comment: Besides, it is bitwise as well.